# Multi Network plugin: "Network not created"

Tags: multisite

I've installed the Multi Network plugin, and when I try to create a new network, I receive "Network not created".

Answer (score 2):

Thankfully in the end, it turns out to be a UI design problem.

Take a look at the “Add New Network” screen.

See the first text box with “Enter network title here” in it?

That doesn’t look like a text entry box…

1. It’s bigger than all the other text entry boxes on the page.
2. It doesn’t have a Description outside the text box itself, the others do.
3. The text box frame is the same width and style as the two boxes below it.

It’s a text box masquerading as a heading!

And if you don’t recognise it as a text box and don’t put anything in it, you get “Network not created”. I hate to think how many people this has happened to who have tried and tried, then given up on the plugin – I was searching for another option before I finally stumbled on what the problem was!